# Blazemeter Multitest Configuration in taurus.yml

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I am running Multiple JMeter scripts (Multi-Test) in Blazemeter where Each script has its own taurus.yml file, So I am running 5 JMeter scripts with 5 taurus.yml, Each time has to edit taurus.yml for concurrency and hold-for.

Is there a way to set same execution values on all scenarios with 1 declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another (6th) YAML file where your `concurrency` and `hold-for` attributes will be specified and use [`included-configs` directive](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Included-Configs) to load the file with concurrency and hold-for into each of 5 files.

This way you will be able to amend the values in one place only.

Comment: I have added another 6th YAML and specified
included-configs:
 - global_data3.yaml
but hold-for value is not reflecting and test is running for indefinite.